# Geolocation.getCurrentPosition return wrong coordinates (0;0)

Tags: android, react-native

I try to get user location (with permission step no problem), but Google approach with his package [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) and method getCurrentPosition return this:

`{"coords": {"accuracy": 3, "altitude": 0, "heading": 0, "latitude": 0, "longitude": 0, "speed": 0}, "mocked": false, "timestamp": 1580744874000}`.

I use [this](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/master/example/App.js) code (example from official documentation).

In brief:

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          this.setState({ location: position, loading: false });
          console.log(position);
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ location: error, loading: false });
          console.log(error);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
```

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` added to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: if you try to getCurrentPosition in that way, it's work?
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          const location = JSON.stringify(position);
          const points: Location = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
          };
})

Comment: Yes, i tried this method, result which i received in console: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition')
requestLocationPermission$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have successfully gained Location Permission, but are you sure that your device has Location enabled?

You can use this library to ask user to enable its GPS: https://github.com/Richou/react-native-android-location-enabler

Answer (score 2):

For others running into this issue, for Android, I had to turn on Bluetooth for the GPS to work. I had location permissions but it was giving me stale coordinates until I turned Bluetooth on. I'm not sure why, but this was the case for me.

Comment: Yeah this was the case with me as well. As i turn on bluetooth the accuracy increases